# PHP get previous directory path of current directory using magic constants __DIR__

Tags: php, include, require

I have custom cron task in my shared hosting and I must include my file using php. Now my folder structure is sample:

```
domain.com
  public_html
    parser
      regions
        other.php
      parser.php
```

I work inside `other.php` file. When I require my file using `require` method:

```
require "../parser.php";
```

getting error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../parser.php'

How I can use PHP magic constants `__DIR__` to get previous directory path of current directory for include my file `parser.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../parser.php';
```

`__DIR__` returns the absolute path to the file it was written in, without a trailing slash. So after it, you can simply append the relative path to the file (with a leading slash).

Comment: I also tried this  `require __DIR__ . '../parser.php';` before asking a question, but it didn’t work and then I asked a question. I see I missed slash ;)